# My label is overlapping with the dropdown list......i want to add space between them

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container">
                <table width=100%>
                      <tr>
                      <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="taborder">
                <tr>
             <td height=25 align="left" class="gtab">Your Contact Details</td>
                 </tr>
                <tr align="left">
                  <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="link">
                    <tr>
     <td width="224" height="29" bgcolor="#DEECF5"> <div align="right"><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                          <form class="form-horizontal">
                           <div class="form-group">
                            <b>Title :</b></div></td>
                                                <td width="326" bgcolor="#DEECF5">
                            <select name="gender" >   
                                 <option <? if ($dataary['gender']=="Mr.") echo "selected"; ?>
                                </option> <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                <option <? if ($dataary['gender']=="Mrs.") echo "selected"; ?> 
                                </option> <option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
                                <option <? if ($dataary['gender']=="Ms.") echo "selected"; ?> 
                                </option> <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                            </select>                           
                        </td>
                        </div>
                     </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="224" height="29" bgcolor="#DEECF5"> <div align="right"><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                        <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">

                        <b> <label for="lnm">Full Name :</label></b></div></td>
                        <td width="326" bgcolor="#DEECF5"> 
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" size="10" name="fnm" class="form-control" value="<?php print $dataary['fnm'];?>"> 
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" size="10" name="lnm" class="form-control" value="<?php print $dataary['lnm'];?>">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <?php print $errors['fullname']; ?>
                                    </td>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                      </tr>
```

My label(Title) is overlapping with the (Mr ,MRs, Ms )dropdown list......i want to add space between them 
and that * should be before label(Title) but it is somewhere up 
it should be like this     * Title: dropdown list

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem and put your css too

Comment: If you have used any CSS, you need to put it here

Comment: @MarcoSalerno   what css should i insert?

Comment: your css or we can't know the issue

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh   i have not used css

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup is wrong:

```
<div class="container">
  <table width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="taborder">
          <tr>
            <td height=25 align="left" class="gtab">Your Contact Details</td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="left">
            <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">
              <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="link">
                <tr>
                  <td width="224" height="29" bgcolor="#DEECF5">
                    <div align="right"><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
                      <form class="form-horizontal">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <b>Title :</b>
                      </div>
                  </td>
```

on this last rule, you are closing the 'td', while you still haven't closed the last 'form' element. I don't know if it has something to do with your issue, but it is advised to have a correct HTML Markup.